# Google Chrome ADMX for non-domain joined PCs

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, windows-registry, group-policy

Does google chrome ADMX policies supports non-domain joined Windows 10 1703 or Windows 7 ent edition machines? I know this sounds stupid... but here is the scenario.

We've few hundred computers and no MS Active Directory Domain. We need to standardize few options in Chrome. 
Such as.. Show Bookmark tab, Set up startup pages etc. but it seems that even if we add the reg keys/values by hand... Chrome doesn't know about that.

We extracted ADMX policies registry information from this link: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

In other tests we found that if the computer is domain joined these policies will work. Either from Group policy method or by manually adding the appropriate registry keys.

Can we tell Chrome on non-domain joined machine to look for same registry store as for domain joined?

Comment: Which edition of Windows 7 are you using?  You should edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Edited and also just tested it on Windows 10...1703 its same behavior.

Comment: Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional or Windows 10 Enterprise, please clarify which editions, of Windows your using

Comment: Its Windows 10 Enterprise.